# How do I remove a project from netbeans without deleting files?

Tags: netbeans

I've got some projects in Netbeans that I don't want it to be aware of anymore since they're slowing down load time. Unfortunately, I've previously made the mistake of right clicking on the project in Netbeans and selecting "delete". When you do that, it gives this scary message:

"This will delete project "MyProject" so that it cannot be opened in the NetBeans IDE anymore."

If you select yes, it makes damn sure you can't open the project in Netbeans anymore by DELETING the project file that's inside the directory.

So my question is: How do I remove a project from NetBeans (8.2) project list WITHOUT losing my project file?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just click on `Close` instead of `Delete`.

Answer (score 2):

Go to File and close project what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on Project Then Choose "Close" From The List